# Starting application before target application

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows Forms application that I need to run before Microsoft InfoPath.

My application needs to have access to any parameters which were passed in to InfoPath.
My application then processes a parameter, has some conditional logic, sets a registry key/value. It then needs to open InfoPath (with any parameters which were passed in first time around) and then close.

Eg

```
1. User opens InfoPath with param "c:\file.xml"
2. BEFORE InfoPath starts I need my application to open and be able to access the
   above param
3. My application does it's stuff
4. My application then starts an InfoPath instance with the param from above
```

Basically I need a middle man. I know how to open InfoPath after using Process.Start but I am unsure of how to "intercept" a user's request to open InfoPath, open my application and then open InfoPath once my application has finished.

Comment: How does the user start InfoPath? Can't you just change the shortcut to your application? Can't you solve this in any other way than messing with the registry?

Comment: The Registry stuff is not related to starting InfoPath. It affects how it behaves but it does not affect how it is open. The user would open InfoPath either by  any InfoPath shortcut or by opening a file which is associated to InfoPath (which is the param I need).

Comment: did you mean, User opening file in windows explorer , when file is opening, your application run before file loading completed?

Comment: Then change the shortcut and associate your application with that extension.

Comment: The shortcut to InfoPath is greyed out, unable to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest replacing the InfoPath executable with your own and afterwards starting the "original one" (which you have stored under a different name of course).